# Symlink is not getting created

Tags: php, php-7

Am trying to create a symlink using PHP function.

```
symlink($target, $source);
$target = '/var/www/html/test/magento/';
$source = '/var/www/html/test/magento/var/log/system.log';
```

But getting an error like

> Warning: symlink(): File exists

Expected result:
***system.log*** should be created as a symlink under ***/var/www/html/test/magento***.

Actual Result:
No symlink is created.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a link called `system.log` inside `/var/www/html/test/magento/var/log`, pointing to `/var/www/html/test/magento/`.

I think what you wanted may rather be

```
$target = '/var/www/html/test/magento/var/log/system.log';
$link = '/var/www/html/test/magento/system.log';
symlink($target, $link);
```

Comment: Awesome :) Thank you so much @Federico